# webサイトの広告による収益の仕組みとその悪用のリスクについて教えてください

Tags: html, web-scraping

個人のウェブサイトなどに広告のバナーが設置されている方法などで収益を稼ぐ方法があると思います。

詳細な料金プランはタイプによって大幅に異なるのでそこは置いておきますが、
広告ページへアクセスされた数で報酬を支払う方式の広告システムは、プログラムによる自動スクレイピング等で「自分の運営するウェブサイトに設置されている広告バナーにアクセス」することで悪質なアクセス回数稼ぎができるのではないでしょうか。

技術的な部分の知識が浅いのでどのような条件の時に可能になってしまうのか、また広告業者側でどのようにアクセス回数稼ぎを検知するのか向学のために教えてください。

個人的にはIPアドレスの偽装までしないとできないのではないかとは思うのですが、広告事業者側の設定で成功失敗は大きく変わってしまう感じでしょうか。

Comment: 主にスクレイピングはWEBページのデータを抽出するような動作を指すので、単に自動化というだけでこの単語を使うのは少し違う気もします。

Comment: cubick様　ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正させていただきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「広告」と謳っている以上は大事なことはアクセス数に対して広告掲載者に対して費用を払うことではなくて、広告主に対し出稿および支払った広告料に対し、効果を出すことが必要です。

広告はその費用対効果に付加価値や競争力があります。

広告を出す以上は自動アクセスや不正な利用で広告料を支払うことは望んでいません。それらを完全に対策することで、費用対効果が上がり、他の広告業者と差別化が図られます。

そのため一般的な対策はもちろんのこと、独自の対策それ自体がその事業の強みになります。
そのため向学のためとはいっても、そこに差別化のポイントがある以上、どういったことをやっているかを学ぶのは難しいでしょう。

広告代理店や広告事業者の企業秘密にあたり、技術もなかなか公開されないことが多いです。
ただわかっていることは、それらを駆使して費用に対しての効果をひたすら上げる努力をしているということです。

Comment: keitaro_so様　ご回答ありがとうございます。そう考えるとネット上で技術的な記事が少ない理由も非常に納得できました。

Answer (score 2):

> 悪質なアクセス回数稼ぎができるのではないでしょうか。

論理的には可能です。

ただし、そのような抜け穴が残っていた場合、悪意ある攻撃者の餌食になり、広告システムは速攻で破産し淘汰されています。存続している広告システム提供者は、そうならないよう考え得る最大限の防御がなされているはずです。

という前提において、一般人が思いつく程度の手法はすべて対策済みなのではないでしょうか？

Comment: sayuri様　ご回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り実際に淘汰（またはルール改訂）された実例を見たことがあります。そういう意味では存続している広告業者の信用力に頼ったほうがよさそうですね。社内の人間が広告事業はどうかとか安直な提案してきてなんと回答したものかと考えておりましたが正当に評価できそうです。　あとスクレイピングの件はたまたまpythonでスクレイピングの技術的な勉強をしていたのもあり、そう言えばと思って聞いてみただけですが確かにpythonなどの言語によって定義できる情報よりも幅広い値でチェックできるであろう相手側のほうが有利そうですね。

Answer (score 1):

仮に純粋なアクセス数 = 広告の表示回数をカウントするのであれば、機械的にアクセスを繰り返さずとも一つのページに100回広告を呼び出すような事も理論的には可能でしょう。

しかし、お金を出す側から考えると、"同一のアクセス元" かどうかはIPアドレスやブラウザの Cookie などを使って総合的に判断していると思われます。

Comment: cubick様　ご回答ありがとうございます。pythonなどのネットのコラムにTorを利用したIPアドレスの分散方法などが転がっていたのでセキュリティー面や不正アクセス対策のコストを重視する必要がありそうですね。